# Fetching Phone Number from android is not properly working

Tags: android, android-contacts

Using phone.NUMBER for fetching the contacts also return brackets. I am testing it on emulator my Emulator stores contact in (XXX)XXX-XXXX so when I use

```
int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
int nameid = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    number = c.getString(phoneIdx);
                    name = c.getString(nameid);
```

number returns (XXX)XXX-XXXX  instead of XXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
number = number.replaceAll("[^0-9,+]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to spilt you number like

```
String mobileno=mobileno.replace("(","");
mobileno=mobileno.replace(")","");
mobileno=mobileno.replace("-","");
mobileno=mobileno.replace(" ","");
```

Then use mobileno.it will come what you have expect :)

Comment: Does it help to you? :)

Comment: I will check it and let you know

Comment: I guess first answer is most reliable just a one line code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
number = number.replaceAll("[-.^()' ']", "")
```